# DataGrouping not working on highcharts angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I'm using angular 11 and these are my dependencies (package.json)

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.10.0",
    ...
```

I' ve got a chart that has dates on the x-axis and numbers on the y-axis and I'm trying to group them with a `sum` approximation.

The chart loads all the data regardless of what I put in the dataGrouping options, this is how I got it set up, it looks pretty standard to me. I've tried increasing the `groupPixelWidth` without getting any result

```
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  highChart!: Highcharts.Chart | null;

  ...
 
  chartOptions: Options = {
    
    ...

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataGrouping: {
          approximation: 'sum',
          smoothed: false,
          enabled: true,
          groupPixelWidth: 2,
          dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            millisecond: [
                '%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L', '-%H:%M:%S.%L'
              ],
              second: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S', '-%H:%M:%S'],
              minute: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '-%H:%M'],
              hour: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '-%H:%M'],
              day: ['%A, %b %e, %Y', '%A, %b %e', '-%A, %b %e, %Y'],
              week: ['Week from %A, %b %e, %Y', '%A, %b %e', '-%A, %b %e, %Y'],
              month: ['%B %Y', '%B', '-%B %Y'],
              year: ['%Y', '%Y', '-%Y']
            },
            units: [
              ['millisecond', []],
              ['second', []],
              ['minute', [30]],
              ['hour', [1, 6, 12]],
              ['day', [1]],
              ['week', null],
                            ['month', null],
                            ['year', null]
                        ]
          }
        }
    },
```

Here's a [public github repository](https://github.com/mauri5566/sitocopy/blob/master/src/app/components/sequences/modal-chart/modal-chart.component.ts) if you want to look at the full code (there might be some merge conflicts I couldn't solve)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how dense is your data however make sure that the data grouping is fired. 
Please check the `groupPixelWidth` property.

You might want to adjust it, or you can set `forced: true` to always calculate the groups.

API:

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.groupPixelWidth
- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.forced

Comment: Still nothing, even with `forced: true` and the `groupPixelWidth` increased. I think it might have something to do with highcharts-angular but I'm unable to find anything

Comment: Could you please share a demo with that issue? Did you import the stock module?

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to Angular, I didn't import the stock module and I can't find a way to do it